# Grammar issue in the review queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, tooltips

I only have access to the review queues on the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange and Ask Ubuntu, but on the First Posts queue, the <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> button has a grammatical issue on the tooltip.

I can't grab a screenshot right now, but on the Ask Ubuntu and RPi SE the tooltip says `this answers seems to be valid` and it should be, at least to be grammatically correct, `This answer seems to be valid`.

Just a heads up, not a huge issue, just something grammar freaks  might notice and freak out on.

Comment: Pluralization bug; will be marked wontfix :P

Comment: What do you mean by Pluralization?

Comment: Sorry, was a reference to https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105 :)

Comment: lol :D Is also a capitalization error.